# File based input to define graph variables

Tags: c++, file, input

I am currently trying to create a program in c++ that will allow a user to fill in a text file to define variables for a graph, these variables define the distance between nodes in the graph. The format is as follows:

```
int numberOfNodes
      //node 0,   node 1 ,   node 2
float distance1, distance2, distance3 //node 0
float distance1, distance2, distance3 //node 1
float distance1, distance2, distance3 //node 2
```

(number of nodes being 3) which is why there is a 3x3 grid, which would specify the distance between each node.

for contect: 
filedata.txt

```
3
0 1 2
1 0 3
2 3 0
```

I understand that to use file input you use fstream, along with ifstream to select the file to open. What I dont understand is how to put this data into context.

How do i tell c++ that the first line will always be how many nodes there are in the list, then how would I tell c++ that anything under that first line is the data I want to fill into their own lists?

```
while (infile >> size)
{
     cout <<"Total number of Verticies in Graph = "<<  size << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input like that:

```
3
```

First read the number of rows, and go into a for loop:

```
infile >> numrows;
for(int row = 0; i < numrows; ++i) {
}
```

The subsequent input can be read as

```
0 1 2
1 0 3
2 3 0
```

---

```
infile >> distance1 >> distance2 >> distance3;
```

inside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I dont think this is what im looking for. i need to read the data from the file, "cin >> numrows" just makes the user type in the data. I need to use the text file to populate the fields

Comment: @Darision Replace `cin` with `infile` dude!

Comment: sorry for the potato moment, that worked a treat, thank you!